# How to do SQL Join with many tables (FK tables have looped results sharing ID)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I am newish to SQL and Join statements and I am way out of my league at the moment
I currently have 6 Database Tables that are all linked to the main 7th table based on the main tables ID, however all the information in the other 6 tables are looped and so have several displayed results to the one main tables ID.

Is it possible to join them all into one Join Statement so I can have a results so that everyones information from the main table also shows their information from the 6 other linked tables

So basically when they all have the informationed joined I want to be able to Display all information on a webpage 
so I was wondering do I need to do multiple JOIN statements or just one Longer one?

I have Included some Images below that explain it visually. See examples 1 and 2

1. The columns that are highlighted in yellow are looped to have many results:

[image: Database Tables Relational link]
 2. This is the example of how the information is looped into the
    database where there are many Race_id sharing to the same inf_id:

[image: Example of the Loop From History Table]

Im not so sure how it will look once it has been joined since some of the information is looped into many Id's and not sure if that means it need to duplicate the column or the rows?? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One of the important parts of using a database engine is knowing what one you're using. You tagged both SQL Server and MySQL in your question; which are 2 very different products. I suspect your using MySQL (As the second picture looks like PHPMyAdmin), however, I've removed both tags for the moment. Please edit your question and tag only the RDBMS you are using. Thanks,

Comment: @larnu ooh im sorry i clicked on the tag that popped up apologies i did not mean to add that one, Yes im am using MySQL -> InnoDB in phpMyAdmin

Comment: @Larnu I hope it is all correct now? and I see you edited the links out and made just the images appear many thanks :)

Comment: dont'post image  only  .. struc  .. post also table schema as text  ..  a proper data sample and the expected  result  (all as text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use left join  eg for the first tables influencer, social, activities

```
select i.*,   s.follower, s.Social_Medial_URL, a.activity, a.result 
from influencer  i 
left join  social s on s.inf_id = i.id 
left join  activities a on  a.inf_id = i.id
```

you can procede yourself adding the left join for the others tables using the same  rules

```
 select i.*
  , s.follower_count
  , s.social_media_url
  , a.compete_activity
  , a.compete_results 
from influencers i 
left join inf_other_social s on s.inf_id = i.id 
left join inf_compete_activity a on a.inf_id = i.id 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the response i think i kinda understand what you are doing (sorry I know some SQL but never done Join statements before properly) do i need to expand out the `s.social_media_url` or can leave as is and what is the like `social s` and `influencer i` ?

Comment: In SQL is possibile assign alias  at table and column name  ..  i is the alias for the table name influencer,  s is the table name for social,  a is the alias  for the table name activities ..  (you can use the shortname you prefer) ..   Your comment about expand a column is not clear to me  Your column name is Social_Media_URL and in the select you must indicate the column name.,. ( or * for all columns) hope is clear ..

Comment: i get an error message when i try that solution i tried expanding it all and then i get a diferent error meesage the message I get is `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 's.follower, s.social_media_url, a.activity, a.results
fr' at line 1`

Comment: i even tried expanding the just letters and still get that tho i also once not sure why but got an error that said something like `column 'influencers' does not exist in 'field list'` which means i was way off since its a table not column

Comment: You have not a column named  `influencers` ..  you have just a table named  `influencer`   .... anyway you should updated  your question and add  your actual SQL code  ... ( i can't image your code)

Comment: changed some of the names to make more sense since i was told my name convention make no sense  
so i changed it accordingly to fit new database names

Comment: This is what phpMyAdmin says

`Error
SQL query: Documentation


select i.*  s.follower_count, s.social_media_url, a.compete_activity, a.compete_results 
from influencers  i 
left join  inf_other_social s on s.inf_id = i.id 
left join  inf_compete_activity a on  a.inf_id = i.id LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 's.follower_count, s.social_media_url, a.compete_activity, a.compete_results 
fr' at line 1`

Comment: `select i.*  s.follower_count, s.social_media_url, a.compete_activity, a.compete_results 
from influencers  i 
left join  inf_other_social s on s.inf_id = i.inf_id 
left join  inf_compete_activity a on  a.inf_id = i.inf_id ` this was the SQL query

Comment: select i.* from
Influencer i 
Left Join Social s on i.inf_id = s.inf_id
Left Join Owned_Equip o on i.inf_id=o.inf_id
Left Join Ages_Interacted a on i.inf_id = a.inf_id
Left Join Activities ac on i.inf_id = ac.inf_id
Left Join Awards aw on i.inf_id = aw.inf_id
Left Join History h on i.inf_id = h.inf_id;

You are missing from clause that's why you get that error

Comment: @scaisEdge, thanks so much my man :) this is the second time i have needed to use a join (the first was just 2 tables with easier inner join) so this is all so hard for me your help is greatly appreciated, just wanted to know it took my table of influencers from 28 people to 1775 results (cause of the loop) that is correct yes?

Comment: @scaisEdge: there is no id column in influencer table as graphically described by Meitie.

Comment: the   join retrieve for each entry in influencer  the related  table in social  and  activities  .. if you have several entries  in the related  table you can obtain a relevant numbers of rows .. this is normal ..

Comment: @Humayoun_Kabir  .. thanks but seems that the OP have already understand the meaning of the answer ..

Comment: @scaisEdge aah okay,so then having it show loads of results is ineed actually correct. thank you, just wanting to know then if i try and take this information onto a web page with this left join statement will it also duplicate it on the page say 28 times for inf_id = 1 or will it just show all the information once? (either way i guess ill find out soon) thank you 100% my man you answer my question perfectly :D

Comment: hey now I am a bit curious as to if this would be best practice in case a user puts loads of fields answers and then i may get a table with over like 100,00 total rows? would that be logical to use this or just connect to each table individual? which would save time on server requests to get the actual information from the database tables

Comment: for better performance  you must think at index ..  adding index  with coint the column involved  in join clause and (eventually also in select at the right of the where involved  column)   and  yes .. normally a  relation is the better way for retrieve data  .. the alternative as a loop that is most time consuming

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about primary key and foreign key. the picture you have given is clearly elaborate everything. as per your db diagram the query might be like this...

```
select * from
Influencer i 
Left Join Social s on i.inf_id = s.inf_id
Left Join Owned_Equip o on i.inf_id=o.inf_id
Left Join Ages_Interacted a on i.inf_id = a.inf_id
Left Join Activities ac on i.inf_id = ac.inf_id
Left Join Awards aw on i.inf_id = aw.inf_id
Left Join History h on i.inf_id = h.inf_id
```

By using this above query you can get all the information of Influencer and related to him (Social,Owned_Equip,Activities,Award etc) whether they exists or not. If you using only "Join" not "Left Join" then you can only find those records which is common for a single influencer to it's related entities/tables which might you say. as an example: say Influencer (id = 1 , suppose name is dan) after inner join we can get only records related to dan ( his social,owned equipments,activites,awards and so on if those tables contains record related to dan record)

Comment: hey @Humayoun_Kabir, I tried your Solution, It runs the query and then the results i get only shows all the information for person from inf_id = 1 (not the rest of the table), and then it duplicates the results of that person 1 a lot (like for my person 1 it duplicated it 28 times) cause of the looped results having like 2 or 3 answers however someone may fill more does that means the inner join could have like 300 results? is that correct? and would it show up like this on my web page? any advice will be accepted

Comment: also i see that for some reason one of the tables that left join didnt loop so it may be more results and im not actually surewhy it didnt loop

Comment: @Meitie , yes it will show 28 records but if you run the query with (\*) , not (i.\* here i is an alias for Influencer) then you might see in some related tables your influencer inf_id is provided as a foreign key 28 times. but all the row including all columns are different from other rows.